# CONTAINS in full-text search does not return all results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I am using full-text search in SQL Server 2008. The following query

```
select * From MyTable where contains( *, 'FLOW AND VALVE')
```

returns two rows:

```
1. FLOW CONTROL VALVE
2. FLOW VALVE
```

but the following query

```
select * From MyTable where contains( *, '"FLOW AND VALVE"'))
```

returns only one row:

```
1. FLOW CONTROL VALVE
```

Why doesn't the second query return the second row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can get some clues from running

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FLOW AND VALVE',1033,0,0)

SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"FLOW AND VALVE"',1033,0,0)
```

`CONTAINS( *, 'FLOW AND VALVE')` is interpreted as two `<simple_term>` searches joined together with a boolean condition. i.e. `CONTAINS( *, 'FLOW') AND CONTAINS( *, 'VALVE')`

`CONTAINS( *, '"FLOW AND VALVE"'))` is interpreted as a phrase search with the "And" ignored as a noise word.

As to why the second one matches "FLOW CONTROL VALVE" but not "FLOW VALVE" [From this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

> Although it ignores the inclusion of stopwords, the full-text index
>   does take into account their position.

so essentially the presence of the stop word acts as a wildcard word match.

Comment: It does seem that noise words are matching any "single" word. e.g. The second query matches this:
"FLOW CONTROL VALVE"

But does not match these:
"FLOW VALVE"
"FLOW METER ADJUSTING VALVE"
"VALVE FLOW"

I cannot find anything in the docs that explain this though.

Comment: @unubar - The phrase search has "Flow" position 1, "And" position 2, "Valve" position 3. As "And" is ignored presumably it just looks for instances of "Flow" in the index which have "Valve" 2 positions later.